# Editing a personal profile in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am creating a web application that allows a users to edit certain fields on their personal profile. The application uses Django forms to update the information. When a users enters in the new information however, the user is sent back to their profile but, the information remains unchanged. Below is how I tried to implement the functionality.

**Form**

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    height = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    weight = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        #Here are the fields that i want editable
        model = User
        fields = ('age', 'height', 'weight')
```

**Views**

```
def update_profile(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account/profile.html'))

    else:
        form = UpdateProfile()
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', args)
```

**HTML**

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is it ok to have it your way `UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)` rather than `UpdateProfile(request.POST)` ?

Comment: Add log in the else part of `form.is_valid()`. It might be the case that your form is not validated and it doesn't seem that you are returning any form errors while redirecting.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm sorry but can you explain what you mean by "add log"? Is that used for debugging in the console?